# I want to redirect user to a specific page upon a code in input

Tags: html, validation, redirect, input

I have an input: `<input type="text" class="redirect"></input>`

And when the user types `A80G`, I want him/her to be redirected to `page1.html`, and when the user types `B6T4`, I want him/her to be redirected to `page2.html`.

Can someone suggest me a way?

My humblest thankfulness.

  -

Comment: Post what you've tried to achieve this

Comment: Your input code is wrong

Comment: Oh, I'd _like_ to know, please, what is wrong?

Comment: And I do not have an idea how to achieve this! Which language shoould I use? PHP? JavaScript?

Comment: For example, Javascript, as I posted.

Comment: And `<input>` doesn't need to be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input class="redirect" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13){if(this.value=='A80G'){window.location.href='page1.html';};if(this.value=='B6T4'){window.location.href='page2.html';}}">
```

Comment: @user3556445 Now? Enter text and hit enter

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use switch case for this

$value = $_POST['input'];

switch ($value) {
    case 'A80G':
       header('location:page-1.html');
        break;
    case 'B6T4':
        header('location:page-2.html');
        break;
    default:
       header('location:page-1.html');
}
```